# Identify this part: two 2x2 plates connected by a strip

Tags: part-identification

Bought a Bulk Lego lot and got some older (1960-1970s) Lego mixed in.  Came across a plate that is best described as a 2x2 plate attached to another 2x2 plate by a thin strip of plastic kind of like a barbell.  The piece is about 2 inches long from plate to plate, I have never seen the this piece before and it is stamped Lego on top of all the studs.  Any help in identifying this part?

Comment: Hi Brandon and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take the time to read the [help] and [tour] pages, then attach a photo of the part to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's gotta be part [650 2x7 hinge plate with 3L bendable coupling nylon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=650):

[image: Part 650]

It only appears in sets from the 1960s, as a means of attaching a vehicle to a trailer.

Comment: I was half-way into typing he same answer and then you posted yours. Can't be anything else.

Comment: I didn't know the time range but this is the part that instantly came to mind even though I haven't done anything with Lego since the early 70s.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scale it could be a [Duplo Bar with 2 x 2 Plates on Ends](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44670#T=C).
[image]

Comment: "The piece is about 2 inches long from plate to plate" I don't think it could be Duplo, unless that's very weird wording for being the length of the bar alone.

Comment: @RSchulz Yes, "plate to plate" could be interpreted as the distance between the inner edges, but TBH I have no idea how long this Duplo bar is (or how it relates to 2 inches).

Comment: Well, each of the 2x2 Duplo plates is about an inch across by itself, so that bar between would be right around 2 inches by my eyeballing it.